# Read from website csv file with variable name

Tags: python, pandas, csv, url

I am using Jupyter and I would like to read csv file from a web site.
The problem I'm facing is that this file changes the name according the time of . For example, if now is **11/21/2019, 02:45:33**, than the name will be "Visao_329465_**11212019_024533**.csv".

So I can't use just this

```
import pandas as pd

url="https://anythint.csv"
c=pd.read_csv(url)
```

Returns the error: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 31, saw 2

Any ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

url="https://anythint.csv"
c=pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Thank's Jortega! Unfortunately it didn't works. Returns many "Skinping lines.." and the data/indexes is missing.